# How to magnify images on hover using purely css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm playing with thumbnail images to save some space on a specific form generated by a loop. The problem was the images was too small to get some attention and I would not sacrifice a few pixels as these images can go from a few to dozens. My solution was to enlarge these images on hover while keeping it simple.

*What I'm trying to say* ( *these are random images i got from the (c) internet* )

[image]

**HTML counterpart**

```
{{#answers}}

<div class="picture-caption">
    <div class="image">
        <img id="{{id}}" class="img-container" src="./data/picture_caption/{{picture_caption}}" alt="your image" onerror="if (this.src != './data/picture_caption/no_image.png') this.src = './data/picture_caption/no_image.png';" />
        <input id="image-value" data-id="{{id}}" class="image-box-{{id}}" type="file" style="display: none;" value=" {{picture_caption}}" />
    </div>
</div>

{{/answers}}
```

**CSS counterpart**

```
.picture-caption {
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}

.img-container {
    margin-left: 14px;
}
.picture-caption img.img-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.picture-caption {
    width: 70px;
    height: 45px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}

.image img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Firefox */
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.image:hover img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform:scale(3); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(3); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(3); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(3); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(3);
}
```

I'm pretty lost here since I just started learning `CSS` and I know `css3` can do amazing things with `html5`

Comment: Do you want the enlarged thumbnail to appear in place, or in another place?

Comment: Should the zoomed image remain inline? In the photo example you showed, it seems like the desired outcome is to fill another container with an enlarged image. If that's the case, you'll probably want to do it with JS. You could do something with radio buttons, but that's not a good method.

Comment: I would like it to float like a modal, In that way it won't be overlapping existing divs. @SwankyLegg

Comment: From the screenshot you need to zoom it out of the main pic and placed in the left? or over the all images?

Comment: I want to place it in the left so that the other images will still be viewable.

Comment: You're going to have to use javascript i'm pretty sure

Comment: why is that? i did pretty fine with css.

Comment: Since you want to put it in another location, you need to programmatically get the src of the img, and then set the other div with that src. You can't do that with css. EDIT: now that i think about it, there is a way you can hack this together with pure css, but it's messy.

Comment: isn't there any zoom attribute in css (e.g. transform:scale) which can handle this? @EricGuan

Comment: I'm trying to solve this but need to know why you're using `<input>` instead of just a `<div>` or nothing at all since you've set it to `display: none` . In the picture you showed, there was no text, and you gave you indication that that content needed to be manipulable.

Comment: Actually, you can replace these images by clicking them and upload a new one. @SwankyLegg

Comment: The `JS` lets the user click the image and trigger `input type file`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was a doubter, but i've managed to hack together what you wanted using only CSS

https://jsfiddle.net/j2w27c6n/2/

```
img:hover ~ underlay{
  top:0px;
  left:100px;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
```

It's easy if you move the thumbnail, like @Jim's answer, but if you need the thumbnail and the magnified version, you have to do some trickery. I put 2 images on top of each other, and when you hover the top img, the bottom img becomes the magnified version.

Comment: brilliant idea, but i was thinking if this is actually a good practice? processing 2 images. imagine, if i have a thousand images.

Comment: It's not, but it's b/c you don't want JS. Why don't you want to use JS? It would be bloody simple.

Comment: just for the sake of simplicity. but if that's the case, could you share how to do it in JS?

Comment: for reasons, i dont like js handling design and stuff but if you say its simplier..

Comment: Well, actually with js it's much simpler than the pure css code i posted. It's possible with pure JS but i'm using jQuery cuz it's easier. https://jsfiddle.net/j2w27c6n/4/

Comment: That is a good reason and I agree with that line of thought. However I think this use case is more logic oriented than design, what with passing src variables around. My pure css code just isn't scalable because i had to have a css hover event for each image, whereas it took just a couple lines of JS to do this, and will work for any amount of images.

Comment: im afraid `<img class="magnify">`  will ruin the design. if there is a way to place this image on top of other divs (maybe make `z-index:999` ?) and make it invisible when not `onHover`

Comment: Yes that's all possible if you know JS. I made it invisible when not hovered, not sure how you wanted the first request. https://jsfiddle.net/j2w27c6n/6/

Comment: I like @EricGuan saying `It would be bloody simple` lolz.

Answer (score 1):

This is just illustration and
See your code as follow:

```
.image:hover img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform:scale(3); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(3); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(3); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(3); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(3);
}
```

Add `position:absolute;` inside the `.image:hover img { ...}` and add `top` and `left` based on your need, including the bigger image you expected.

Answer (score 1):

Please checkout this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jimedelstein/xjc154wz/1/

CSS ends up looking like this:

```
.picture-caption {
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}

.img-container {
  margin-left: 14px;
}

.picture-caption img.img-container {
  width: 70px;
  height: 45px;
}

.picture-caption {
  width: 70px;
  height: 45px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.image:hover img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 0;
  width: 210px;
  height: 135px;
}
```

It's more or less what @herman-nz suggests.  There is a lot more that could be done to improve the solution, but I think this is along the lines of what you are looking for.

Comment: beautiful. actually i'm doing something like this at the moment. credits to @Herman Nz